# MySql query on three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Help needed, I have three table "USERS", "FRIENDS" and "STATUS" i am having difficulty joining them by condition in the "FRIENDS TABLE"

```
 users table
id | name | usercode
--------------------
1 | david | 2WM
2 | Samme | E5N
3 | Awudu | C0Q
4 | John  | VX6
5 | Jerem | FG3

Friends Table
id | actor | target
--------------------
1  | E5N   | FG3
2  | 2WM   | VX6
3  | FG3   | 2WM
4  | C0Q   | VX6
5  | FG3   | VX6

 Status Table
id | usercode | status
--------------------
1  | E5N      | I am busy now
2  | 2WM      | The night is falling too fast
3  | FG3      | Good day
4  | C0Q      | Very tired, trust me
5  | VX6      | YeLLLLOOO
```

What i will like to get is all "users" from "USERS TABLE" and their corresponding "status" from the "STATUS TABLE" who either has 'FG3' as "target" or 'FG3' as "actor" from the "FRIENDS TABLE"

So the results will be like

```
id | name  | usercode | actor | target | status
------------------------------------------------
 2 | Samme | E5N      | E5N   | FG3    | I am busy now
 1 | david | 2WM      | FG3   | 2WM    | The night is falling too fast
 5 | John  | VX6      | FG3   | VX6    | YeLLLLOOO
```

Please any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: First try to join 3 tables and then have a where clause with your conditions

Comment: I have tried a lot of queries and i dont know which if them i will post for your help that is why i did not add any of them

Comment: How is the friends table related to the other tables? I don't understand the relationships from the column names

Comment: Does UserCode have any special significance? Im wondering about your table design for starters. why not just use the ID from the users table in the status table and not have an 'ID' column in friends table? Unless the status table is a preset list of status's why have a status table? why not just have a status column in the users table?

Comment: the usercode is also a unique identification for each user, what makes it significant is if a user delete their account and later rejoin they will lose their id because of auto increment but still maintain their usercode which they can use to access their history on the site. So you can treat the usercode just like the user id

Comment: Assuming 1 user can have only 1 status, why do you have a status table?

Comment: @GB because status table is also linked to another table called status_replies with one to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.name,
       u.usercode,
       f.actor,
       f.target,
       s.status
FROM Users u,
    Friends f,
    Status s 
WHERE ((u.usercode = f.actor AND 'FG3' = f.target)
OR (u.usercode = f.target AND 'FG3' = f.actor)) 
AND s.usercode = u.usercode
```

Answer (score 1):

First, join your user table with the friends table, then, join the status table with the friends table

```
SELECT friend_user.name,
       friend_user.usercode,
       Friends.actor,
       Friends.target,
       friend_status.status
FROM users AS my_user_table
JOIN Friends ON Friends.actor = my_user_table.usercode
JOIN users AS friend_user ON friend_user.usercode = Friends.target
OR friend_user.usercode = Friends.actor
JOIN Status AS friend_status ON friend_status.usercode = friend_user.usercode
WHERE my_user_table.usercode = 'FG3'
```